# Enough with the bold italic and editing every old question, please

Tags: discussion, editing, formatting

EDIT 2.25: At the time of this writing, *every single question* on the main page has been touched by Bybe, covering the span of a single hour. Newer topics going back as much as 21 hours(at which point I stopped looking) have been completely buried in Questions/Newest.

As much as I hate having to call out a single person: @bybe I've been biting my tongue on this for a while, but it's getting obnoxious with the recent barrage of edits on seemingly every old question, regardless of need or effectiveness. (It's also pushing down actual new topics, but that's for another time.)

In [this thread](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34389/why-do-some-webmasters-avoid-putting-direct-links-on-their-pages), *which has already been resolved*, a series of questions which were already set apart just fine was:

1. Moved into an ordered list.
2. *Every item made italic.*
3. ***And then bold on top of it***.

That's just one of the more egregious examples. Links are already (bright) blue and don't need to be [additionally bolded](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/43520/4502).
Have some trust in people's ability to read. Bold italic actually *detracts* from this and just makes people feel like you're yelling at them.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this to my attention I guess people determine different styling methods differently and agree this can be seen differently from user to user and in the best interest of the community I will from here onwards stop using excessive italic and bold on list items.

It's worth noting that not all my edits contain such excessive use of italic, but point noted.

Also I'd like you to address the bumping of old posts, how can this be avoided? I don't see old posts being edited for grammar, spelling and containing 404's unworthy edits. it's not my intention to bump old posts, far from that in fact.

Thanks again.

Comment: We're going to disagree on whether editing old threads is worth it. But editing old *resolved* threads is debatable at best, as far as I'm concerned. And to be blunt I question how rigorous you can be about it at the rate you're going. You incorrectly stripped a link from one of my own answers just today as 404 when it's perfectly accessible. I don't have the inclination to dig around for more examples.

Comment: Bumping newer topics is unavoidable. It's how the system works by design. What you're bringing up is basically a variation of [this meta topic](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/936/minor-edit-capability-on-own-questions-answers) re not making edits that don't substantially help the topic. To a prior comment: resolved topics don't need more help, usually. Circumventing your activity requires users go to the Questions tab, and then the Newest tab under *there*. (Also, it remembers if you were on eg. FAQ, so *more* annoying.) It's not viable for you to expect everyone do that.

Comment: Well I have to disagree... Because your rollbacked to a previous edit of mine just reverts the problem. The link in question is http://drupal.org/node/206724 and its 403... I.e Forbidden and no good for anyone. I check every single link and they are not just mindless ZAP ZAP ZAP's! I even checked that link with various status headers such as Webconfs. I suggest you recheck http://drupal.org/node/206724 as it doesn't work at all. And editing old posts removing unless pages isn't necessary useless. A site with 10% of pages that contain 404's might become a problem.

Comment: And to recomment once again, yes the link is now working which would indicate that Drupal was having problems. My bad.. But again its worth noting 99.9% of my edits have not been of this nature of 403s. Apologizes, Thanks for rolling back. But if you ever do get the time to review my edits your see that 99.9% are acceptable or least I hope they are.

Comment: I'll chill out with the edits and stick to answers I think ;)

Comment: Thanks for backing off, bybe.  My RSS reader gets all of the posts you edit as if they were new posts, which makes it harder for me to answer questions effectively.  I think most of your edits have been good, but the way that stack bumps edits makes your approach unwieldy.  I've had good luck with specifically editing titles of unanswered question in a way that they would attract more attention so they get answered, so the bumping functionality can certainly be useful.

Comment: @bybe It wasn't said explicitly, but editing posts for spelling/grammar or if they have genuine mistakes is fine and encouraged. (Generally best to only do a few at a time.) Editing formatting (especially adding bold and italic) when the current posts are perfectly clear is pointless.

Comment: @bybe: Please stop to edit all these questions!

Comment: Sorry.... I'm adding tags and can't help myself when I see spelling mistakes and grammar that just makes no sense.. Should I ignore them because people rather click active questions over new questions..

Comment: The edits are not changing words from the to 'The' etc. Seems no matter how big the edit people frown upon such things.

Comment: @bybe: Please, you just want to get a badge.

Comment: Really? Virtual badges are just pixels, I do it because I enjoy it. If I wanted a badge I'd go work in mac donalds and get a real badge with 5 stars. Please consider for one moment that people use stack exchanges because they enjoy the community and actually enjoy using the site in many ways more than just answering questions.

Comment: @bybe Without wishing to offend, your own spelling and grammar leaves a great deal to be desired. You're not apt for a position policing the spelling and grammar of others. Your activities most certainly are _not_ enhancing _my_ enjoyment of this community, nor does it appear to be endearing you to others – perhaps you should consider, for one moment…

Comment: @bybe: Congratulations for having just gained the _Copy Editor_ badge.

Comment: and? @Zistoloen I don't see how its relevant its just pixels.

Comment: @GDav point noted and no I'm not offended at all, I'm pretty sure that a lot of people have better grammar skills than myself and could also easily edit my edits and further improve on the quality of the content on the site - But with this said I think this is intended by Stack's and one of the reasons after awhile with edits they enter into wiki's. If you see mistakes by myself then just edit but I feel the majority of my edits are improvements and this is how the 'Edit' should be used.If one person edits and its improved then GREAT! if another person edits and makes it even BETTER! GREAT!

Comment: I'm getting to much spot light here, I retire.

Comment: @bybe Not so. Your edits, for the most part, are trivial and so suggest a failure to consider the big picture. The fact that you routinely misuse "your" when you mean "you're", for example, isn't _really_ so detrimental to your being understood that it's worth mine or anyone else's time correcting it. When such trivial edits are made _en masse_ the results do not serve but substantially _damage_ people's experience of this site. So your appeal to the ethos of Stack Exchange does nothing to support your actions.

Comment: No need to further hasten the judgements of my actions, I have said I retire and therefor no need to carry on this debate. Thanks for all your feedback.